# Miller-Rabin algorithm

Tags: number-theory, homework, prime-numbers

I want to implement the Miller-Rabin algorithm in *Mathematica* to check if a number is prime with at least 99.99% probability. I used this:

```
MillerRabin[n_, k_] := 
  Module[{d = n - 1, s = 0, test = True},
    While[Mod[d, 2] == 0, d /= 2; s++] 
    Do[
      a = RandomInteger[{2, n - 1}];
      x = PowerMod[a, d, n];
      If[x != 1,
        For[r = 0, r < s, r++, If[x == n - 1, Continue[]]; x = Mod[x*x, n];];
        If[x != n - 1, test = False];];,
      {k}];
    Print[test]]
```

But I don't understand what it means. For instance, if I write `MillerRabin[7, 5]` I get `True`, but what does the 5 stand for and how can I see the probability?

Comment: Where did you get the code from in the first place?

Comment: @blochwave The instruction sheet with the questions (homework), I am given the code but I dont really know what it mean. Thats what I am trying to figure out.

Comment: I belive you are missing a semicolon (;) at the end of `While[Mod[d, 2] == 0, d /= 2; s++]`

Comment: I think your instructor probably gave you guidelines for determining the probability of `n` being prime given `k` witnesses to noncompositeness. You should use them. There are several analyses in the literature, but I haven't kept up with them. What you're supposed to use probably depends on the level of the course.

Comment: If a number causes `True` to be printed, there is no way to get a numerical estimate of probability that it is a prime from any simple modification your code. On the other hand, if a number causes `False` to be printed, it is certain that the number is composite

Answer (score 1):

You seem pretty new to *Mathematica*.

First things first, so: `k` is the number of times, the `Do` loop will run.

Now, to more "second" things: Giving you *Mathematica* code without having *Mathematica* at your hands seems unlikely, so you should really take a look at *Mathematica*'s fine documentation (not flawless in every dark crevice, though, but nevertheless really informative). You should have no problem understanding the code, if you start out by getting online help on all "keywords" (in *Mathematica* terms: Symbols) here, e.g.:

`Module`, `Do`, `While` etc.